# Is there a better way than this to find out if an IsolatedStorage file exists or not?

Tags: c#, silverlight, isolatedstorage

I'm using **IsolatedStorage** in a **Silverlight** application for caching, so I need to know if the file exists or not which I do with the following method.

I couldn't find a **FileExists** method for IsolatedStorage so I'm just catching the exception, but it seems to be a quite **general exception**, I'm concerned it will catch more than if the file doesn't exist.

**Is there a better way to find out if a file exists in IsolatedStorage than this:**

```
public static string LoadTextFromIsolatedStorageFile(string fileName)
{
    string text = String.Empty;

    using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        try
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isfs = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName,
                            FileMode.Open, isf))
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(isfs))
                {
                    string lineOfData = String.Empty;
                    while ((lineOfData = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                        text += lineOfData;
                }
            }
            return text;
        }
        catch (IsolatedStorageException ex)
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the "manual" (.net framework 2.0 Application Development Foundation):

Unlike the application programming interface (API) for files stored arbitrarily
in the file system, the API for files in Isolated Storage does not support checking
for the existence of a file directly like `File.Exists` does. Instead, you need to ask the
store for a list of files that match a particular file mask. If it is found, you can open the
file, as shown in this example

```
string[] files = userStore.GetFileNames("UserSettings.set");
if (files.Length == 0)
{
Console.WriteLine("File not found");
}
else
{
    // ...

}
```

Comment: thanks that helped me figure out what I was missing, actually, as it turns out, you can use userStore.FileExists() (Silverlight 3)

Comment: Good observation, you do have an IsolatedStorageFile.FileExists() method, but only in  .net 4 (I'm not working with 4.0 yet). For earlier versions you can use the example above.

Comment: on my current machine I only have 3.5 installed and IsolatedSTorageFile.FileExists() works

Comment: I have 3.5 and I don't have the FileExists method ... (also on msdn the supported framework for IsolatedStorageFile.FileExits is 4.0)